# How to get/connect database field value in backend of wix

Tags: javascript, database, velo

I hope you guys familiar with Wix, & you will suggest me a good answer, right now I'm developing a website with 3rd party API. Here I'm trying to get database value in my backend which is used to get the result in front end using the repeater.

My code is working fine when I'm using const, below is the code so you will understand what I want to achieve -
Remember it's a **jsw file**

Full Example I'm trying to code in the backend so I can call in frontend using the repeater

```
import { fetch } from 'wix-fetch';
import wixData from 'wix-data';
export async function getData() {
const apiKey = "apikey";
//const idCall = "value";
let idCall = wixData.get('#myDatabaseName', 'title'); //Here i want to take values from my database.
//imaginary url example below
const response = await fetch("https://www.exampleapi.com/data/d5/feed?&id=" + idCall + "&key=" + apiKey, {
method: 'get' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable **idCall** in your fetch call when there is no such defined variable in your code.

wixData.get() requires an item id to retrieve the item.

On top of that you cannot send the entire item in the url. you need to specify which field key you want to use. such as **id.fieldKey**

Your code should be like

```
let id = await wixData.get('#myDatabaseName', itemId);

const response = fetch("https://www.exampleapi.com/data/d5/feed?&id=" + id.fieldKey + "&key=" + apiKey, {
method: 'get' });
```

Comment: let id = await wixData.get('myDatabaseName', 'title');                                               
Error: Cannot read property 'title' of null (remember all code is on backend side),  Item Id is Field Key right?

Comment: You need to read the documentation (https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference//wix-data.html#get) You MUST give an item id with which the function will retrieve the item from the said database. 'title' is just a placeholder.

Comment: let id = await wixData.get('myDatabaseName', 'title')

  .then((results) => {
   let title = results;
   //console.log(title);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
   let errorMsg = err;
  });
const response = fetch("https://www.exampleapi.com/data/d5/feed?&id=" + id.title + "&key=" + apiKey, {
method: 'get' });

 if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
  const res = await response.json();
  return res;
 }
 let res = await response.json();
 return res;
} **Now what i'm doing wrong- Error: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined** @Shan

Comment: Hey, @Shan I think you mention the above code for frontend but I'm trying to connect database field value from backend using ***.jsw***. I tried everything but every time I'm getting an error because itemId is for front end not for backend I think. I hope you now understand. Please look once again on ques/code & suggest me